# VBA excel code running time

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the below code to enter the current value of cells into a string array. There are 52k+ rows and when running in debug mode if I place a break on the 2nd "Do" the code runs really fast (seconds)  after I press F5. If no break is entered then it takes a very long time (6-8 minutes).

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Best,
Nasos

```
Do
    ProjectIDPub(i, 0) = Cells(3 + i, 13).Value & " - " & Cells(3 + i, 3).Value
    ProjectIDPub(i, 1) = Cells(3 + i, 7).Value
    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = numberRowsAXProjectsSheetPub

i = 0
Do
    Cells(3 + i, 14).Value = ProjectIDPub(i, 0)
    Cells(3 + i, 15).Value = ProjectIDPub(i, 1)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = numberRowsAXProjectsSheetPub
i = 0
```

Comment: I dont understand. Why dont you do that at once?

Comment: If you have working code which merely needs improvements then you're probably in the wrong place with this post. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is where they handle existing / working code and do their upmost to improve it in terms of speed, security, sustainability, and longevity including best-practices. Give it a try. They're good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `numberRowsAXProjectsSheetPub` is the number of rows in the array `ProjectIDPub`, the entire second loop can be replaced by

```
Range(Cells(3,14),Cells(3 + numberRowsAXProjectsSheetPub - 1,15)).Value = ProjectIDPub
```

It is almost always much faster to transfer an array to the worksheet in a single assignment rather than in a loop.

Comment: Thank you so much John I adjusted your code slightly and this worked perfectly

Comment: Hi John, I tried the same method with a one dimensional array and it only transfered the first element out of the 30k lines. `code Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(3 + numberRowsEcosSheetPub - 1, 4)).Value = projectIDPub`

Comment: @Nasos In Excel, ranges correspond to 2-dimensional arrays, even when they only have 1 column. This is a well-known annoyance. There is a work-around involving using the worksheet function `Transpose` -- but I don't think it works with 30k lines. The simplest fix is to always use 2 dimensional arrays, even if 1 dimension is fake: just declare `projectIDPub` as e.g. `Dim projectIDPub(1 to 30000, 1 to 1)` and just use `projectID(i,1)` instead of `projectID(i)`. This is tedious, but is sometimes the best way to deal with 1-column ranges as VBA arrays. If so, the assignment will work as is.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: somewhat inconsistently you *can* directly assign the values of a 1-dimensional array to a range contained in a single row. The problem pops up when you try to put a 1-dimensional array into a column-range. Since you can assign to a row and can transpose a row to a column, you can do something like `MyColumnRange.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray)` -- but there is a limit to the size of the arrays that the `Transpose` function can handle.

Comment: Thanks again John the transpose solution worked perfectly even for the large number of lines 52.7k

Comment: Also considering your solution for `projectID(i,1)` with a 2 dimensional array that would require a loop to give the expected result I assume?

Comment: I think that the limitations on `Transpose` were for older versions of Excel. I remember this sometimes being an issue for me. It looks like it isn't an issue anymore with more recent versions of Excel. My idea about using a fake 2-D array was to have it be 2-D even from creation. This wouldn't require any conversion. Note that if `A` is variant then something like `A = Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1000,1)).Value` makes `A` into one of these artificially 2-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running those loops with screen update disabled?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do
ProjectIDPub(i, 0) = Cells(3 + i, 13).Value & " - " & Cells(3 + i, 3).Value
ProjectIDPub(i, 1) = Cells(3 + i, 7).Value
i = i + 1

Loop Until i = numberRowsAXProjectsSheetPub
i = 0
Do
    Cells(3 + i, 14).Value = ProjectIDPub(i, 0)
    Cells(3 + i, 15).Value = ProjectIDPub(i, 1)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = numberRowsAXProjectsSheetPub
i = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

And as @ali-srn asked, why do you need to run the same loop twice? If the second loop access some data that needs to be created by the first one you should be able to alter it with some offset for `i` if needed and just run once.

Comment: I have tried with the screen disabled. I also tried running it in one go but it did not really affect in any way the time needed to complete the operation.

Comment: That's odd that disabling screen updating before modifying cells did not affect the execution time. I always find it mandatory when looping through a lot of cells and modifying their content.